# How to edit or add a specific value to a JSON in Python

Tags: python, json

I have this function: `def SetData(Username, Data):`.

I have a JSON file called "data.json" and want to know the best way to make a value with the person's "Username" and add the "Data" value to it. I also want to make sure that it will override any existing values with that username. Please note I have never coded with Python and this is my first project, so this is probably a really dumb question.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your question isn't dumb at all! Everyone starts somewhere, and I'm here to help. Let's break down the problem and provide you with a step-by-step solution using Python.

You want to create a function `SetData(Username, Data)` that updates a JSON file (`data.json`) with the provided `Data` for a given `Username`. Here's how you can approach this:

1. **Load Existing Data:** Read the contents of the JSON file into a Python data structure.
2. **Update Data:** Update the data structure with the new `Data` value for the given `Username`.
3. **Write Data Back:** Write the updated data structure back to the JSON file, effectively saving the changes.

Here's the code to accomplish this:

```py
import json

def SetData(Username, Data):
    # Step 1: Load Existing Data
    with open('data.json', 'r') as file:
        existing_data = json.load(file)
    
    # Step 2: Update Data
    existing_data[Username] = Data
    
    # Step 3: Write Data Back
    with open('data.json', 'w') as file:
        json.dump(existing_data, file, indent=4)  # indent for human-readable formatting

# Usage example
username = "example_user"
data_value = "new_data_value"
SetData(username, data_value)
```

Please note:

- Make sure you have the `data.json` file in the same directory as your Python script.
- This code assumes that the JSON file initially contains a dictionary where the keys are usernames and values are associated data.
- The function will update existing values or add new ones if the username doesn't exist.

Remember, when working with code and data, it's always a good practice to make backups and test thoroughly.

Updated for list type:

If your `data.json` file is a list, and JSON file looks like this:

```json
[
    {
        "Username": "user1",
        "Data": "data1"
    },
    {
        "Username": "user2",
        "Data": "data2"
    },
    ...
]
```

Here's how you can modify the code:

```py
import json

def SetData(Username, Data):
    # Step 1: Load Existing Data
    with open('data.json', 'r') as file:
        existing_data = json.load(file)
    
    # Step 2: Find and Update Data
    for item in existing_data:
        if item["Username"] == Username:
            item["Data"] = Data
            break  # No need to continue searching if we found the username
    
    # Step 3: Write Data Back
    with open('data.json', 'w') as file:
        json.dump(existing_data, file, indent=4)  # indent for human-readable formatting

# Usage example
username = "example_user"
data_value = "new_data_value"
SetData(username, data_value)
```

Please replace the JSON structure and the field names in the code with the actual structure of your `data.json` file. This code will search for the username in the list and update the associated data if the username is found. If not, you can decide whether you want to add a new entry or handle it differently.

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for the quick reply! After testing this code, I get this error:    
    "existing_data[Username] = Data
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Comment: It seems like the structure of your data.json file is a list, not a dictionary.

Comment: I will update the ans with list type.

Comment: Oh yeah! I forgot to clear the file from earlier testing lol, it works now! Thank you so much!

Comment: Why do you open the file twice instead of using, for example, 'r+' ?

Answer (score -1):

First of all you need to decide on what the file structure is going to look like - i.e., is it a single JSON object or a list of objects. Then you need to consider what happens if the file doesn't exist or has an incorrect structure - e.g., not valid JSON

Let's assume that you want your JSON file to contain a list of JSON objects then:

```
import json
from pathlib import Path

FILENAME = Path('data.json')

def SetData(Username, Data):
    def _entry(username, data):
        return {
            'Username': username,
            'Data': data
        }
    try:
        mode = 'r+' if FILENAME.exists() else 'w'
        with open(FILENAME, mode) as f:
            jdata = [] if mode == 'w' else json.load(f)
            if isinstance(jdata, list):
                for e in jdata:
                    if e.get('Username') == Username:
                        e['Data'] = Data
                        break
                else:
                    jdata.append(_entry(Username, Data))
            else:
                jdata = _entry(Username, Data)
            f.seek(0)
            json.dump(jdata, f, indent=2)
            f.truncate()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```